# How can i force a margin (right and left to 50px) on the body tag of my page for screen sizes above 1280px

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Please i have written the some css to target the body tag and set its margin (right and left to 50px) when a screen reaches 1280px and above.

Here's a code snippet of what i have done so far.

---

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

body{
  margin-left: 50px !important;
  background-color: #F0F0F0 !important;
  margin-right: 50px !important;
}   
}
```

---

Comment: And what is the result you are seeing? Are you getting no margin/ a larger margin? Also, do you need all those classes on the body element?

Comment: Not even seeing the custom code definition in Developer tools on chrome. No effect on the margin. No i don't . I just thought it would help but its not.

Any ideas please --FluffyKitten

Comment: If you don't need the extra classes, don't use them - it is too easy to target the wrong thing and the styles won't be applied to what you actually want. If you're not seeing the rule in developer tools, then its quite possible thats whats happened.

Comment: The css is correct, I just tried it in a fiddle and it works fine.  Are you sure the selector is correct?  Show us the html.  Try just using `body {...}`, there is only one body element, there is no need to use the other classes when selecting it.

Comment: i just targeted the the body tag with the home class. still no effect

Comment: Please include your HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need 50px margin from left and right the code below can help you:

```
  @media (min-width: 1280px)
  {
    body
    {
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
  }
```

However I suggest you to use percentage using something like width: 95% is better

Comment: How is this any different to the code that is in the question?

Comment: it wasn't body tag that he wanted to apply margin in the first place and he seems that edited his question